# Why does \mitsans#1 command (unicode-math) still produce upright sans serif in math mode

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, sans-serif

I never thought that sans serif letters are subset of the glyphs in unicode OpenType fonts, until I see this in `texdoc unimath-symbols`:

[image]

However, I cannot get the italic shape of sans serif letters in math mode by using the command `\mitsans<letter>`. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[range=sfit]
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

$\msansH$  $\mitsansH$ 

\end{document}
```

[image]

I complied with xelatex, under the TeX Live 2015 distribution, with the newest packages before TeX Live 2015 frozen.

As you can see in the image, indeed they are sans serif, but they are of the same shape. I cannot get italic sans serif in displaystyle either. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `\symsfit{H}` does the thing

Comment: @egreg That works, thank you! So the old commands no longer work?

Comment: The command `\mitsansH` *ought* to work. This needs investigation.

Comment: It seem to be a `unicode-math` bug.  To verify consider [this plain TeX example](http://hastebin.com/mujobohaya.tex) and contrast it with [this LaTeX example](http://hastebin.com/irupokoliv.tex).